# Log to Crashlytics with tag and priority without also sending to logcat

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

There are two ways to log to Crashlytics according to the [documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html?#custom-logging).

1. `Crashlytics.log(int priority, String tag, String msg);`

   In addition to writing to the next crash report, it will also write to the LogCat using `android.util.Log.println(priority, tag, msg)`.
2. `Crashlytics.log(msg);`

   which will only write to the Crashlytics crash report [not logcat].

However, this second method does not allow me to set a tag and priority. Instead it automatically sets the resulting tag as "CrashlyticsCore" and priority to debug:

From Fabric dashboard:

```
1   |   04:24:55:100 (UTC)  |   D/CrashlyticsCore ...
2   |   04:24:55:101 (UTC)  |   D/CrashlyticsCore ...
3   |   04:24:55:121 (UTC)  |   D/CrashlyticsCore ...
```

How can I keep my actual tag and debug value? I suppose I could create a custom message but this seems ugly and would just clutter up Fabric:

```
String output = String.format(Locale.US, 
    "Priority: %d; %s : %s", priority, tag, message);
Crashlytics.log(output);
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here and I'm not quite clear what you mean. Do you mean to how to keep Crashlytics logs always written out to LogCat or something else?

Comment: @MikeBonnell thx. I updated my question. I want to show tag and priority in Fabric dashboard and I want to NOT show logs in logcat.

Comment: Ahh, yes, you would need to manually work around it then. We don't have a built out solution for that.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to log tags in Crashlytics but avoid them in LogCat using `Crashlytics.log(int priority, String tag, String msg);` I would recommend to enable `SilentLogger` for Fabric:

```
// Create Crashlytics Kit which doesn't trace crashes in debug mode
final Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder().core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build()).build();

// Use SilentLogger instead of DefaultLogger to avoid writing into LogCat 
Fabric.with(new Fabric.Builder(this).kits(crashlyticsKit).logger(new SilentLogger()).build());
```