# Log exception to crashlytics without logging to logcat

Tags: crashlytics, android-logcat

After experimenting with `Crashlytics.logException(throwable)` I see that it *always* logs to logcat in addition to sending to Crashlytics. This is not acceptable for release builds. So how can I disable logging to logcat? I know there are different versions of `log()`, which I asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49001291/1650674), but I only see one version of `logException()`.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I haven't been able to reproduce this locally. As far as I can see, logException never logs to Logcat. Is it possible you have another logging mechanism that's doing that work?